# java Reading list of list of files

Tags: java, file-io

Can someone help me with reading a list of list of csv files. Like

```
List<List<File>> filesList;
```

Want to read through all the files contents in each list for processing, but unable to comeup with loop structure which can be used. Thanks.

UPDATE: I want to load files from each inner file list simultaneously. Like read first file from each inner list at a time, compare contents, then move to second file of a particular list and so on. Each inner list can be of variable size.

Comment: @tbodt Want to read files from each list at a time, not sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use `Iterator`,like this

```
    List<ArrayList<File>> filesList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<File>>();
    //add objects to filesList here

    Iterator<ArrayList<File>> filesListIterator = filesList.iterator();

    while(filesListIterator.hasNext())
    {
        ArrayList<File> files = filesListIterator.next();

        Iterator<File> filesIterator = files.iterator();

        while(filesIterator.hasNext())
        {
            File file = filesIterator.next();
            //do your own logic here;
        }
    }
```

**Update**
This may help you for compare

```
 while(filesListIterator.hasNext())
    {
        ArrayList<File> files = filesListIterator.next();

        for(int i=0;i<files.size()-1;i++)
        {
            File firstFile = files.get(i);//get a file

            File secondFile = files.get(i+1);//get the next file

            compareFiles(firstFile,secondFile);//this is your defined   
                                             //method for compare
        }
    }
```

Comment: related: http://blog.goyello.com/2013/05/17/express-names-in-code-bad-vs-clean/ :D

Comment: @prabhaker Want to read files from each list at a time, not sequentially

Answer (score 4):

Here's an appropriate loop for this:

```
for (List<File> innerList : filesList) 
    for (File file : innerList) 
        // do something for a file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<List<File>> filesList;
    for (List<File> list : filesList) {
        for (File file : list) {
            // your code here ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: @tbodt Don't down vote competing answers. [This is bad etiquette](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175241/is-it-bad-etiquette-to-downvote-a-competing-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend using Google Guava if you can, this has a `concat` method

```
    final List<List<File>> files = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (final File file : Iterables.concat(files)) {
        //doStuff with file
    }
```

Comment: I do not agree to add an external library to solve such simple problem. You have to link with your external library and you have to maintain it within your project. This is a bazooka to kill a fly. That's ok if Guava is already part of your project, otherwise...